# Get original perl on RHEL 6

Tags: perl, rhel6

I know  it was foolish but I uninstalled perl. When I reinstalled it using YUM it has several dependency issues.

How can I get perl in its original form? The one which is distributed with RHEL.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

```
yum install perl
```

should be enough. YUM will resolve any dependency issue automatically.

Comment: I already installed it using yum install perl but I am facing many dependency issues which were not there previously.

Comment: @AshishPaliwal Please include those output of YUM in your question. By the way, how did you remove your `perl`?